# Electromagnetic waves in a plasma

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, plasma-physics

I am looking for an intuitive explanation of the response of cold plasmas with refractive index $n=\sqrt{1-\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2}}$ to electromagnetic waves.

All of the explanations I can find say that for $\omega<\omega_p$ the electrons react 'quickly enough' to cancel the incident wave so it is fully reflected, and for $\omega>\omega_p$ the electrons cannot respond quickly enough to fully cancel it so it is able to propagate.

However, these explanations don't match up with the mathematical result for the transmitted electric field (found by setting $n=\sqrt{1-\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2}}$ in the Fresnel equation for a normally incident wave), $$E_t=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2}}}E_i.$$
This shows that the electrons actually reinforce the field, so surely the explanations which talk about them cancelling cannot be correct.

Comment: Can you please give links/names for those references you've consulted?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/366916/137185 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191110/137185 for example.

Comment: Where's the second equation from?

Comment: What are the assumptions to arrive at your second equation?

Comment: Just the usual Fresnel equation where I set $n$ equal to that of the plasma.

Comment: For $\omega < \omega_p$ the index of refraction becomes imaginary, and the wave solution in the plasma becomes evanescent (i.e. it does not propagate)